# Last logged in always never, not logging

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

I turned on logging module, it works, but no logs in log_customer or log_visitor. Those tables are empty. What else can block logging? Magento 1.9

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found what was wrong. Someone from earlier extended Mage_Log_Model_Visitor and changed

```
protected $_skipRequestLogging = false;
```

to true. So it was skipping here:

```
public function saveByRequest($observer)
{
    if ($this->_skipRequestLogging || $this->isModuleIgnored($observer)) {
        return $this;
    }

    try {
        $this->setLastVisitAt(now());
        $this->save();
        $this->_getSession()->setVisitorData($this->getData());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

That was stopping from all logging, even if in config it was on.